# awk to filter file by specific field in another

Tags: awk

I am trying to filter a specific field (`$7`) in `file2` using `file1` (which is just a list of unique id's).  The `awk` below runs but does not filter the file (it remains unchanged).  Thank you :).

**file1**

```
ACTA2
ACTC1
AGRN
```

**file2**

```
Chr Start   End Ref Alt Func.refGene    Gene.refGene    GeneDetail.refGene
chr1    977330  977330  T   C   intronic    AGRN    0
chr1    981931  981931  A   G   exonic  AGRN    0
chr1    982994  982994  T   C   exonic  AGRN    0
chr1    1269554 1269554 T   C   exonic  TAS1R3  0
chr1    1647778 1647778 C   G   intronic    CDK11A  CDK11B
chr1    1647814 1647814 T   C   exonic  CDK11A  CDK11B
```

**desired output**

```
Chr Start   End Ref Alt Func.refGene    Gene.refGene    GeneDetail.refGene
chr1    977330  977330  T   C   intronic    AGRN    0
chr1    981931  981931  A   G   exonic  AGRN    0
chr1    982994  982994  T   C   exonic  AGRN    0
```

**awk**

```
awk 'NR==FNR{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) a[$i];next} !($7 in a)' file1 FS="[ =]"  file2 > output.txt
```

`a[$i]` is used to put all items in file1 into array `a`, `NR==FNR` used to ensure only file1 is used. in second part, set the `FS` to space or `"="`, and compare if `$7` in `file2` is in this array a or not, if it is then print it.

Comment: Thank you very much :).  I thought I needed the loop to iterate though file1 but I see now that I was not right, thanks again :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just remove the `FS="[ =]"` between file1 and file2 and replace `!` with 
`FNR==1 ||`

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) a[$i];next} FNR==1 || ($7 in a)' file1 file2

Chr Start   End Ref Alt Func.refGene    Gene.refGene    GeneDetail.refGene
chr1    977330  977330  T   C   intronic    AGRN    0
chr1    981931  981931  A   G   exonic  AGRN    0
chr1    982994  982994  T   C   exonic  AGRN    0
```

of course you don't need the for loop

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next} FNR==1 || ($7 in a)' file1 file2
```

Answer (score -1):

you don't need to use `awk` you can use grep

```
grep -f file1.txt file2.txt
```

then you can write a simple bash script

```
#!/bin/bash
head -1 file2.txt
grep -f file1.txt file2.txt
```

output

```
Chr Start   End Ref Alt Func.refGene    Gene.refGene    GeneDetail.refGene
chr1    977330  977330  T   C   intronic    AGRN    0
chr1    981931  981931  A   G   exonic  AGRN    0
chr1    982994  982994  T   C   exonic  AGRN    0
```

Comment: this won't restrict the match to only one field.

Comment: nor will it restrict it to a whole field, it'll do a partial match so if `file1` contains `AGRN1` and file2 contains `AGRN12` then it'll be treated as a match. It'd also duplicate the header line if it contained a partial match to anything in file1.